# How to get dimensions in original language

Tags: google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get something like the Google analytics dashboard but I have some troubles with the language of the result of my query.
When I get the result of my query, I get all the names in English but the geochart only understands the local names.

So when I get for example "Brittany" as a ga:Region, the geochart will not understand it and so won't show it on the map whereas "Bretagne" will. That's the same for all translations.

Do you have any idea of how I could have either the region in the original language or have the geochart understanding the english name of the region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Analytics API returns values only in English.  Unfortunately you are going to have to translate them yourself.